# Plane simulation within the Unity Editor for the ARFoundation package

Tags: debugging, unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, arkit, arcore

I've been using the [experimental-ARInterface](https://github.com/Unity-Technologies/experimental-ARInterface) GitHub project to develop AR apps for both `ARCore` and `ARKit` in Unity. This project had a useful tool to simulate ARPlanes in the Unity editor itself. I can develop the entire app without any AR enabled device and finally build the app to a device.

Now that project is deprecated and I have to use the [ARFoundation](https://docs.unity3d.com/Packages/com.unity.xr.arfoundation@1.0/manual/index.html) package. So my question is: are there any ways to simulate the `ARPlane` in this package in the editor itself? And is there any other way I can develop AR apps without a AR enabled device required all the time?

Comment: I am still facing this issue. I am not sure if in-editor simulation is available in AR Foundation. Any suggestion?